# Replace all matches EXCEPT first match in multiple files with perl

Tags: perl

I need to do a find/replace in multiple files but I want to keep the first occurrence of the match and replace all others. THis may have been answered else where but it's a bit difficult to search for.

I am currently using: `perl -pi -w -e 's/THING/SOMETHING_ELSE/g;' ./src/**/*.py`

A practical example:

```
from stuff import THING

print(f"use {THING} here")
print(f"use {THING} there")
print(f"use {THING} everywhere")
```

Should become:

```
from stuff import THING

print(f"use {SOMETHING_ELSE} here")
print(f"use {SOMETHING_ELSE} there")
print(f"use {SOMETHING_ELSE} everywhere")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check for `/THING/` before doing the `s/THING/.../`.

Here's how would be as a script `thing-to-other` that you can then call as `thing-to-other ./src/**/*.py`

```
#!/bin/env perl -i -p

if ( /THING/ ) {
    if ( $seen{$ARGV}++ ) {
        s/THING/SOMETHING_ELSE/g;
    }
}
```

Note that I got rid of the `-w` because the use of the `%seen` hash will throw a warning.  The `%seen` hash keeps track how many times in each input file (`$ARGV`) you've seen `/MATCH/`.

If you really need it to be a one-liner:

```
perl -i -p -e'if (/THING/) {if($seen{$ARGV}++){s/THING/SOMETHING_ELSE/g}}'
```

Comment: Note that this likely fails the task if THING shows up in any other case besides the actual line the OP is trying to skip. That might be in a comment, as a substring in something else, and so on.

Comment: Indeed. OP could change that check for /THING/ into a more specific pattern that would then set a per-file flag that would tell whether to do the substitution or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to skip the `from` line, so I'd just skip those. This expression either matches that `from` or tries to do the substitution. That is, the substitution is not attempted on any line that starts with `from`:

```
$ perl -pi -w -e 'm/^from\s/ or s/\bTHING\b/SOMETHING_ELSE/g;' test.py
from stuff import THING

print(f"use {SOMETHING_ELSE} here")
print(f"use {SOMETHING_ELSE} there")
print(f"use {SOMETHING_ELSE} everywhere")
```

This skips every `from` line, so if you wanted to change other `from` lines, this isn't going to work.

Notice that I also use the `\b` word anchor boundaries around `THING`. Otherwise, you get what I got I ran the program again: `SOMESOMETHING_ELSE_ELSE` :)

There are various other ways to accomplish this task but they aren't so nice as one-liners.